# Add more fieldnames to an existing struct

Tags: string, matlab, struct

If I have a struct, handles,

```
handles = struct('a',1,'b',2,'c',3)
```

I also have a cell of strings and a cell of numbers

```
cell1 = {'d','e','f'};
cell2 = {4,5,6};
```

How do I add the field names from cell1 to handles with values from cell2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though there is likely a more efficient method, the first thing that comes to mind would be utilizing [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html):

```
handles = struct('a',1,'b',2,'c',3);

cell1 = {'d','e','f'};
cell2 = {4,5,6};

for ii = 1:length(cell1)
    handles.(cell1{ii}) = cell2{ii};
end
```

Which returns:

```
handles = 

    a: 1
    b: 2
    c: 3
    d: 4
    e: 5
    f: 6
```

Comment: This is probably quite an efficient method for this example.

Comment: @horchler I was thinking there would be a good way to use the struct built with `cell2struct(cell2, cell1, 2)` but all the structure merging functionality I've seen has a lot of overhead.